# Is 'town' or 'Barrie' a proper noun in this sentence?

Tags: proper-nouns

> I live in a small town called Barrie.

Which noun is proper – *town* or *Barrie*?

I answered *Barrie* and the examiner marked it as wrong.

And another one:

> Last night, I watched the movie My Cousin Vinny on television.

In this sentence, is *Cousin* a proper noun or a common noun?

Comment: This can easily be checked in any basic general reference guide: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun

Answer (score 4):

A proper noun is a name. You were correct to answer Barrie. "Cousin" is not a proper noun in the title given (although "Cousins", being a surname, can be a proper noun in the right context).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have to fight for some marks :)

Comment: "Cousin" can be used as a proper noun even if it's not a surname. For example, "Hey Cousin, come over here". More common is "Why isn't Dad here yet?".

Comment: Yes, tenfour I agree with that. But in this case it looks like Cousin is 'My Cousin' Vinny rather than My 'Cousin Vinny'. So I am thinnking Cousin is common.

Comment: @tenfour, I disgree about "cousin". I would write your example as "Hey, cousin, come over here"; the lower case being a strong indicator that it isn't a proper noun. "Dad", OTOH, when unqualified ("your dad"), I agree about.

Comment: *My Cousin Vinny* as a whole is a [proper noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun), since it's a name (of a movie), but not *My* or *Cousin* individually.  (*Vinny* is intrinsically proper, though.)

Comment: I guess the distinction between capitalizing Dad vs. Cousin is another question for EL&U :) I can't say for sure.

Comment: You can't tell if 'Cousin' is proper or common in 'My Cousin Vinnie'. You can't judge by capitalization because it's in a title. And you can't tell by usage because the usage is consistent either way. I lean slightly toward proper because, at least to me, 'Cousin Vinnie' seems like his title. Like 'Prince Edward' in 'Our Prince Edward'.

Comment: @David Schwartz, "cousin Vinnie" can be a proper noun without "cousin" being a proper noun.

Comment: I know of no town to which I have given my name. There is, however, a town called Barry in Wales.

Comment: You capitalize *cousin* in the same places where you capitalize *uncle*.  If you are talking about your cousin or your uncle, you don’t, but if you are talking about Uncle Tom and Cousin Wilbur, then you do.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Well, if you ever do, please make sure Ada lives in it and link it here!